# how to filter a json data using javascript

Tags: javascript, json

I have this issue guys, i'm not able to filter my json data, this is a complexe one but, I hope I can get an answer tho.

```
{
    "jQRReponse": [
        [{
            "sujet": "RHONE ALPES",
            "verbe": "11"
        }],
        [{
            "sujet": "ALSACE",
            "verbe": "22"
        }],
        [{
            "sujet": "ALSACE",
            "verbe": "55"
        }]
]
}
```

So how can I filter this json object for example by `sujet === "ALSACE"`.
Thank you

Comment: what kind of result you want. I mean object?

Comment: yeah I meant sujet, thank you I will update it

Comment: I just want a json object as result

Comment: You can do it by this, https://jsfiddle.net/ry7bz3L2/

Comment: this is not filtring by but actually finding an item :s

Comment: what do you want man actually? Can you give me the exact result that you are expecting?

Comment: i'm expecting a json object which contains : 
 [{
            "sujet": "ALSACE",
            "verbe": "22"
        }],
        [{
            "sujet": "ALSACE",
            "verbe": "55"
        }]

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ry7bz3L2/1/